# using Regex how do I capture the exception message only without stack trace

Tags: regex, regex-group, re2

I have this text:

```
System.FormatException: String '' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. at Application.Mappers.AutoMapperProfile.<>c.<.ctor>b__0_92(CartCampaignDto x, CartCampaign y) in /build/src/Application/Mappers/AutoMapperProfile.cs:line 60 at lambda_method543(Closure , Object , Cart , ResolutionContext ) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at lambda_method543(Closure , Object , Cart , ResolutionContext ) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I'm trying to match only this part

`System.FormatException: String '' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

I tried

`^(.*) at.*)`

`^(.+)(?=at ){1}(.*)`

but it didn't work.

**EDIT:**

This is not in any programming language, this is to build a `NewRelic` dashboard where you can add a Regex to get some insights.

**EDIT 2**
NewRelic uses Google/R2 Regex

**EDIT 3**
I'm trying to build this query

```
SELECT uniqueCount(1) From Log where `@l` = 'Error' FACET capture(`@x`, r'(?P<anyvarname>^(.*?\.)\s*at\b)')
```

**EDIT 4** Not sure why this doesn't work

[image]

Comment: Something like `^.*?\.(?=\s*at\b)`? See https://regex101.com/r/TzX2pe/1

Comment: What is the programming environment? What are exact pattern requirements?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no specific one, just a search in a text. I updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Does `^(.*?\.)\s*at\b`work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my bad, it turned out it is a specific version of Regex called R2. 
While your suggestion work in Regex101.com, it doesn't work in NewRelic.

Comment: See [RE2 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TzX2pe/2), it works there. There is no `R2` regex flavor. If it is a line in a multiline text, try `m` flag, `(?m)^(.*?\.)\s*at\b`

Comment: If you need a named group, try `(?m)^(?<ex>.*?\.)\s*at\b`

Comment: Try it like this `(?P<anyvarname>(.*?\.)\s*at\b).*`  https://regex101.com/r/dovQWj/1

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for your:

```
^.+\.\s
```

Quickly breaking it in pieces:

- **^.+**  -> matches, from the beggining of the line, any 1 or more characters
- **\.\s** -> matches a dot followed by a whitespace.

[image: testing the regex]

Comment: This works in a normal text, but it turned out that NewRelic uses Re2, so didn't work the same for some reason.

Comment: @Nour This pattern is RE2 compliant.

Comment: @LeYAUable I'm putting the same expression in a named group as required by NewRelic
`r'(?P<ex>^(.*?\.)\s*at\b)` does that change anything?

Comment: I guess you then need to get the captured instead of just the capture of the entire regex.
I don't have experience with NewRelic but Wiktor said that the pattern is compliant.

Comment: typo above, should be "...get the captured group instead..."

Answer (score 0):

You could write the pattern matching the whole line with a named capture group:

```
(?P<anyvarname>(.*?\.)\s*at\b).*
```

See these pages for more information about capture

- https://newrelic.com/blog/how-to-relic/using-regex-capture#toc-how-regex-capture-works
- https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/query-your-data/nrql-new-relic-query-language/get-started/nrql-syntax-clauses-functions/#func-capture